# Result is not correct--C Programming

Tags: c

Good day to everyone. 
I have a question. How to fix my incorrect result as shown here, on my **Point Obtained** part, Round 1, the result is not correct? The answer is should be 34 for player 1, 45 for player 2, 50 for player 3.

Also, I also know that fflush(stdin) is not suitable to be implemented in coding. But when I remove fflush(stdin), the fgets is skipping my input. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this?

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int round;
int player;
char name1[30];
char name2[30];
char name3[30];
int total1;
int total2;
int total3;
int times;
int point[3];

total1=0;
total2=0;
total3=0;

printf("======League of Legends======\n");

printf("How many round?:");
scanf("%d", &round);

printf("How many player:");
scanf("%d", &player);

fflush(stdin);

printf("Name player 1:");
fgets(name1, 30, stdin);

printf("Name player 2:");
fgets(name2, 30, stdin);

printf("Name player 3:");
fgets(name3, 30, stdin);

for(times=1; times<=round; times++)
{
    printf("## Round %d ##\n", times);
    printf("Point for player 1(%s):",name1);
    scanf("%d", &point[0]);

    printf("Point for player 2(%s):", name2);
    scanf("%d", &point[1]);

    printf("Point for player 3(%s):", name3);
    scanf("%d", &point[2]);

    total1=total1+point[0];
    total2=total2+point[1];
    total3=total3+point[2];

}

 for(times=1; times<=round; times++)

 {
    printf("******Point obtained******\n");

    printf("## Round %d ##\n", times);
    printf("Point for player 1(%s): %d\n", name1,  point[0]);

    printf("Point for player 2(%s): %d\n", name2,  point[1]);

    printf("Point for player 3(%s): %d\n", name3,  point[2]);

 }


printf("++++++TOTAL POINT++++++\n");
printf("Total point player 1(%s):%d\n", name1, total1);
printf("Total point player 2(%s):%d\n", name2, total2);
printf("Total point player 3(%s):%d\n", name3, total3);

return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". - You might like to [edit] your question, for example: instead of posting images of text better post the text as such.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of getting wrong output is that the array `point` is overwritten by information of later round. You have to store the data separately.

To fix `fgets()` problem, I will read all lines via `fgets()` to have them read newline characters.

possible fix:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int readInt(void) {
    char buffer[512];
    int ret;
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &ret);
    return ret;
}

void readString(char* str, size_t str_size) {
    char* p;
    fgets(str, str_size, stdin);
    for (p=str; *p!='\0' && *p!='\n'; p++);
    *p='\0';
}

int main(void)
{

    int round;
    int player;
    char name1[30];
    char name2[30];
    char name3[30];
    int total1;
    int total2;
    int total3;
    int times;
    int (*point)[3];

    total1=0;
    total2=0;
    total3=0;

    printf("======League of Legends======\n");

    printf("How many round?:");
    round=readInt();

    printf("How many player:");
    player=readInt();

    printf("Name player 1:");
    readString(name1, sizeof(name1));

    printf("Name player 2:");
    readString(name2, sizeof(name2));

    printf("Name player 3:");
    readString(name3, sizeof(name3));

    point=malloc(sizeof(*point)*round);

    for(times=1; times<=round; times++)
    {
        printf("## Round %d ##\n", times);
        printf("Point for player 1(%s):",name1);
        scanf("%d", &point[times-1][0]);

        printf("Point for player 2(%s):", name2);
        scanf("%d", &point[times-1][1]);

        printf("Point for player 3(%s):", name3);
        scanf("%d", &point[times-1][2]);

        total1=total1+point[times-1][0];
        total2=total2+point[times-1][1];
        total3=total3+point[times-1][2];

    }

    for(times=1; times<=round; times++)

    {
       printf("******Point obtained******\n");

       printf("## Round %d ##\n", times);
       printf("Point for player 1(%s): %d\n", name1,  point[times-1][0]);

       printf("Point for player 2(%s): %d\n", name2,  point[times-1][1]);

       printf("Point for player 3(%s): %d\n", name3,  point[times-1][2]);

    }

    free(point);

    printf("++++++TOTAL POINT++++++\n");
    printf("Total point player 1(%s):%d\n", name1, total1);
    printf("Total point player 2(%s):%d\n", name2, total2);
    printf("Total point player 3(%s):%d\n", name3, total3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm very appreciate that!

But I have a question, actually how to read the strings with perfectly? I mean reading the strings without skipping inputs

I have searched a lot about this, some people say put fgets(), sscanf() and so on, but I have tried these in my previous coding, but sometimes they will skip my inputs. 

So can you suggest me what is the best way to read the strings?